# What is the minimum size of a value in Lua

Tags: lua, size, sizeof

What is the minimum size that a value can have in Lua? For example one number.

This knowledge is especially useful when calculating the size that an array of values will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how a [Value](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#Value) is defined in Lua 5.3:

```
#define TValuefields    Value value_; int tt_

/*
** Tagged Values. This is the basic representation of values in Lua,
** an actual value plus a tag with its type.
*/

/*
** Union of all Lua values
*/
typedef union Value {
  GCObject *gc;    /* collectable objects */
  void *p;         /* light userdata */
  int b;           /* booleans */
  lua_CFunction f; /* light C functions */
  lua_Integer i;   /* integer numbers */
  lua_Number n;    /* float numbers */
} Value;


#define TValuefields    Value value_; int tt_


typedef struct lua_TValue {
  TValuefields;
} TValue;
```

[`GCObject`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#CommonHeader) is defined like this:

```
/*
** Common type for all collectable objects
*/
typedef struct GCObject GCObject;


/*
** Common Header for all collectable objects (in macro form, to be
** included in other objects)
*/
#define CommonHeader    GCObject *next; lu_byte tt; lu_byte marked


/*
** Common type has only the common header
*/
struct GCObject {
  CommonHeader;
};
```

[`lu_byte`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/llimits.h.html#lu_byte):

```
/* chars used as small naturals (so that 'char' is reserved for characters) */
typedef unsigned char lu_byte;
```

[`lua_CFunction`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.h.html#lua_CFunction):

```
/*
** Type for C functions registered with Lua
*/
typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L);
```

[`lua_Integer`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.h.html#lua_Integer):

```
/* type for integer functions */
typedef LUA_INTEGER lua_Integer;
```

The definition of `LUA_INTEGER` [depends on the platform and build settings](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html) but is usually a 64 bit signed integer.

[`lua_Number`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.h.html#lua_Number):

```
/* type of numbers in Lua */
typedef LUA_NUMBER lua_Number;
```

`LUA_NUMBER` is also dependent on the configuration and platform, but is usually a `double`.

So to get the minimum size, you have to calculate the following (under the assumption that all pointer types have the same length):

```
max(sizeof(pointer), sizeof(int), sizeof(LUA_INTEGER), sizeof(LUA_NUMBER)) + sizeof(int) + padding
```

On x86_64 this would usually be:

```
sizeof(pointer) + sizeof(int) + padding  = 8 + 4 + 4 = 16
```

32 bit x86:

```
sizeof(double) + sizeof(int) + padding = 8 + 4 + 4 = 16
```